# Put multiple Attachments to CouchDB

Tags: c#, json, couchdb

I have an .NET Core console application which does some update stuff to my CouchDB.
Now I have to add multiple attachments (in this case images) to my doc.

Here (https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/api/document/common.html#attachments) in point 1.4.1.1.4 they describe the way, but I get a Bad Request, I think my json is not perfect.
So I have a list of images that I convert and then send to DB, here is my code:

```
List<ImageFromApi> imagesFromApi = new List<ImageFromApi>();
            string base64String;
            foreach (var image in Images)
            {
                using (image)
                {
                    using (MemoryStream m = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        image.Save(m, image.RawFormat);
                        byte[] imageBytes = m.ToArray();

                        // Convert byte[] to Base64 String
                        base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);
                    }
                }
                ImageFromApi Imagebuffer = new ImageFromApi() {
                    content_type = "image/*",
                    data = base64String                
                };
                imagesFromApi.Add(Imagebuffer);
                DocAttachments bufferData = new DocAttachments() {imagesFromApi = imagesFromApi };
                newImages._attachments = bufferData;
            }

            string imagesJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(newImages);
            using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
            {
                streamWriter.Write(imagesJson);
            }
            var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
```

My Json from this code looks like this:
[image: MyJson]

I see the difference between mine and the one from the documentation, but I dont know how to change my json correctly.

Any solutions?

Comment: Not your only problem, but `image/*` is an invalid content type. You need something like `image/jpeg`, for example.

Comment: I don't know C#, so can't tell you exactly how to fix this in your code, but it appears that your `_attachments` data is an array. `_attachments` should be a map of filename to file data. i.e. `{"_attachments":{"image1.jpg": {"content_type":"image/jpeg","data":"..."},"image2.jpg":{"content_type":"image/jpeg","data":"..."}}`.

Comment: Yes, i know that this is the problem, but i dont know how to fix it. I am looking around for solutions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So that nobody had a solution, i tried something around and find a way to achieve what i need. I made a new Attachment and added each image manually.
Here is an example of the first image:

```
Attachments attBuffer = new Attachments();

using (imagesFromApi[0])
            {
                using (MemoryStream m = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    partImgs[0].Save(m, partImgs[0].RawFormat);
                    byte[] imageBytes = m.ToArray();
                    // Convert byte[] to Base64 String
                    base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);
                }
            }

            attBuffer.Hood = new Hood()
            {
                content_type = "image/jpeg",
                data = base64String,
            };
```

As you can see, i created any of my images as a class and then mapped the list to it. I think this is not the best way, but it works for me, so better than nothing.

Hope it helps you as well.